# Dual of Absolute Quadric for camera self calibration

Tags: matlab, computer-vision, camera-calibration

Dual of Absolute Quadric (DAQ)

Just wondering if someone in this group has worked with accurate estimation of Dual of Absolute Quadric for camera calibration?
Any code in Matlab?

Answer (score 1):

[libmv](http://code.google.com/p/libmv/) has a C++ implementation of the linear self-calibration technique described in the paper "Visual modeling with a hand-held camera" by Pollefeys et al.  I don't know whether that code works, though;  libmv seems to still be in the early stages of development.

Comment: Thanks, but like you said that code doesnt seem to be complete. I can use Matlab codes too, if any.